# Stata odbc SQL multiple CTE in one query

Tags: sql, stata, common-table-expression

I'm trying to conduct a multiple CTE expression within the "odbc load, exec("WITH..." statement. I confirmed the two CTEs extract the information needed.

However, Stata doesn't appear to like the use of two CTEs. I tried to separate the two, like SQL states, with a semicolon, but it returns "Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Any advice?  Here is my code to view:

```
. #delimit ;
delimiter now ; 
. odbc load, exec("
> WITH BIRegionSIC (Region, BranchID, Branch, SIC, CoreMarket, MarketSegment)
>         AS
>         (
>         SELECT
>                 [A].Region,
>                 [A].BranchID,
>                 [A].Branch,
>                 [B].SIC,
>                 [B].[Core Market] AS CoreMarket,
>                 [B].[Market Segment] AS MarketSegment
>         FROM
>                 [B]
>                 INNER JOIN [A]
>                 ON [B].Region = [A].Region
>         )
> ;WITH cteRNE (Year, Month, SoldTo, BranchID, cteSales)
>         AS
>         (
>         SELECT 
>                 Year([Invoice Date]) AS Year, 
>                 Month([Invoice Date]) AS Month,
>                 [Sold to (Number)] AS SoldTo,
>                 [Sales Office] AS BranchID,
>                 Sum([Invoiced Sales]) AS cteSales
>         FROM [A]
>                 INNER JOIN [Sales]
>                 ON [A].BranchID = [Sales].[Sales Office]
>         WHERE [A].Region = 'NE'
>         GROUP BY
>                 Year([Invoice Date]),
>                 Month([Invoice Date]),
>                 [Sales Office],
>                 [Sold to (Number)]
>         )
> SELECT
>                 BIRegionSIC.Region,
>                 BIRegionSIC.BranchID,
>                 BIRegionSIC.Branch,
>                 BIRegionSIC.CoreMarket,
>                 BIRegionSIC.MarketSegment,
>                 cteRNE.Year,
>                 cteRNE.Month,
>                 SUM([cteRNE].[cteSales]) AS Sales
>         FROM
>                 (
>                 cteRNE 
>                 INNER JOIN
>                         [C]
>                         ON cteRNE.SoldTo = [C].[Sold To]
>                 )
>                 INNER JOIN
>                         BIRegionSIC
>                         ON cteRNE.BranchID = BIRegionSIC.BranchID
>         GROUP BY
>                 BIRegionSIC.Region,
>                 BIRegionSIC.BranchID,
>                 BIRegionSIC.Branch,
>                 BIRegionSIC.CoreMarket,
>                 BIRegionSIC.MarketSegment,
>                 cteRNE.Year,
>                 cteRNE.Month
>         ORDER BY
>                 BIRegionSIC.Region ASC,
>                 BIRegionSIC.BranchID ASC,
>                 BIRegionSIC.Branch ASC,
>                 BIRegionSIC.CoreMarket ASC,
>                 BIRegionSIC.MarketSegment ASC,
>                 cteRNE.Year ASC,
>                 cteRNE.Month ASC
> ") 
> dsn(sourcefile) clear;
The ODBC driver reported the following diagnostics
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ';'.
SQLSTATE=42000
r(682);

end of do-file

r(682);
```

Thanks for any advice! I delimit so the code is readable in the do-file, and running without the delimiter set to semicolon results in the same error.

Regards,

Ryan

Comment: I should add that without the semicolon separating the two CTEs, I get error: "If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change in tracking context clause, the previous staement must be terminated with a semicolon."

I am unable to find a method to separate the long line into many without delimiting with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare multiple CTE's in the following way:

```
WITH cte AS (
)

, cte2 AS (
)
```

Not by using the `WITH`-clause multiple times.

Comment: That did the trick! It's always the little things that are always overlooked.